# DETOX Build Error ( error: package android.support.annotation does not exist import android.support.annotation.NonNull )

Tags: android, react-native, android-support-library, detox

running command 
`detox build --configuration android.emu.debug` 
gives the following error

when i try to detox build on linux it gives this error related to androidx but it works fine on a mac.

It appears the issue is specific to how gradle is using jetifier, as the android support packages don't seem to be replaced on Linux

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detox:minReactNative44DebugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1.
  Required by:
      project :detox
   > Cannot find a version of 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' that satisfies the version constraints:
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.4.1' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.4.1
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.4.1' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.4.1
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.4.1' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.4.1
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.10.0'--> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.11.0'--> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'

> Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0.
  Required by:
      project :detox
   > Cannot find a version of 'com.squareup.okio:okio' that satisfies the version constraints:
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0'
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.9.0' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.9.0
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.9.0' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.9.0

> Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1.
  Required by:
      project :detox
      project :detox > com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1
   > Cannot find a version of 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' that satisfies the version constraints:
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.4.1' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.4.1
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.4.1' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.4.1
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.4.1' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.4.1
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.10.0'--> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.11.0'--> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'

> Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0.
  Required by:
      project :detox > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8
      project :detox > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8 > com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.11.0
   > Cannot find a version of 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' that satisfies the version constraints:
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.4.1' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.4.1
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.4.1' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.4.1
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.4.1' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.4.1
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.10.0'--> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.11.0'--> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'

> Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0.
  Required by:
      project :detox > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8
      project :detox > com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0
   > Cannot find a version of 'com.squareup.okio:okio' that satisfies the version constraints:
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0'
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.9.0' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.9.0
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.9.0' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.9.0

> Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0.
  Required by:
      project :detox > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8 > com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.10.0
   > Cannot find a version of 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' that satisfies the version constraints:
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.4.1' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.4.1
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.4.1' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.4.1
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Constraint path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.4.1' because of the following reason: minReactNative44DebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.4.1
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        Dependency path 'testrepo2:detox:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.10.0'--> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could read these guidelines before asking a new question. Thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you build the app using `react-native run-android` on the linux system?

Comment: yes i can build the app using `react-native run-android` I have also recreated this issue in a test project https://github.com/Lokendra-rawat/rnn-detox/tree/master